# How can i disable a particular tab in tabbar, to be able to click?

Tags: dart, flutter

is there a way to disable a particular tab in the tabbar? so that it cannot be clicked unless it is enabled again?  any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Code with Absorb/Ignore Pointer not working:

```
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => new _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Widget>[
Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    AbsorbPointer(
child: Tab(text: 'RIGHT')), //not working
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return new Center(child: new Text(tab.text));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using AbsorbPointer

Comment: its not workin when i wrap AbsorbPointer around a Tab widget, maybe the gestures on the tabs  are accessed from anywhere else?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu done, please  see the updated question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go:

Add list to make which tab is disabled

```
List<bool> _isDisabled = [false, true];
```

Add a listener to `_tabController`

```
_tabController.addListener(onTap);
```

`onTap()` method. If selected tab is disabled we will revert to previous selected tab.

```
onTap() {
  if (_isDisabled[_tabController.index]) {
    int index = _tabController.previousIndex;
    setState(() {
      _tabController.index = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Below is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<bool> _isDisabled = [false, true];

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  onTap() {
    if (_isDisabled[_tabController.index]) {
      int index = _tabController.previousIndex;
      setState(() {
        _tabController.index = index;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    _tabController.addListener(onTap);
  }

  @override
    void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return Center(child: new Text(tab.text));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, i will try it out soon to see if it works.

Comment: Take your time, if have any doubts please ask.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked as expected,

I wanted to ask if this logic can also be used to disable swiping too? like if the next tab is listed as disabled, then we cant swipe forward to the next disabled tab but we can swipe backwards?

Comment: Try using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/swipedetector, I will update my answer later, currently having exams

Comment: This solution did work for tapping. For swiping I set the physics on the `TabBarView` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me

```
TabBar(
onTap: (value) {
       if ( (_tabController?.indexIsChanging ?? false) &&
              _tabController?.index == disableIndex) {
            _tabController?.index = _tabController?.previousIndex ?? 1;
          }
        })
```

Answer (score -9):

```
TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)), //enabled
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit), onTap: null), //disabled
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation to why this is a solution. Thanks

Comment: there is no such property as "onTap" in a tab.

Comment: `onTap` is a parameter for the `TabBar`.